# Equivalence of Definitions of Principal $G$-bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

I've finally gotten around to learning about [principal $G$-bundles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_bundle).

In the literature, I've encountered (more than) four different definitions.  Since I'm still a beginner, it's unclear to me whether these definitions are equivalent or not.  I would appreciate any clarification.

All maps and group actions are assumed continuous.

> **Definition 1:** A principal $G$-bundle is a fiber bundle $F \to P \xrightarrow{\pi} X$ together with a right action of $G$ on $P$ such that:
>
> (1) $G$ acts freely and transitively on fibers.
>
> (2A) $G$ preserves fibers.

---

> **Definition 2:** A principal $G$-bundle is a fiber bundle $F \to P \xrightarrow{\pi} X$ together with a left action of $G$ on $F$ (note $F$ here) such that:
>
> (1) $G$ acts freely and transitively on $F$.
>
> (2B) There exists a trivializing cover with $G$-valued transition maps.

---

> **Definition 3:** A principal $G$-bundle is a fiber bundle $F \to P \xrightarrow{\pi} X$ together with a right action of $G$ on $P$ such that:
>
> (1') $G$ acts freely on $P$ and $X = P/G$ and $\pi\colon P \to X$ is $p \mapsto [p]$.
>
> (2C) There exists a trivializing cover that is $G$-equivariant.

---

> **Definition 4:** A principal $G$-bundle is a fiber bundle $F \to P \xrightarrow{\pi} X$ together with a right action of $G$ on $P$ such that:
>
> (2A) $G$ preserves fibers.
>
> (2C) There exists a trivializing cover that is $G$-equivariant.

---

**Thoughts:** It seems to me that Definition 4 is **not** equivalent to the other three.  More than anything else, I am unclear as to why the existence of a trivializing cover that is $G$-equivariant is equivalent (is it?) to the existence of one that has $G$-valued transition functions.

I've also seen a fifth definition which assumes only condition (1).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is another one: a principal $G$-bundle is a fiber bundle with fiber $G$ and structure group $G$ where $G$ acts on itself by left translations. This is the definition of Davis & Kirk.

Comment: @BrunoStonek, can you please help me with [this definition of principle bundle (bounty offered)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3395875/this-definition-of-principal-g-bundle-might-be-missing-details-like-fiber-pres)? I don't think there's any notion of structure group of this volume of Tu's books, though Bott and Tu of course discuss structure groups in another volume.

Comment: What is $F$? Isn't it always $G$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In fact, these definitions are not equivalent and are not equivalent to the usual notion of a principal $G$-bundle, see e.g. Kobayashi-Nomizu "Foundations of differential geometry", Vol. I, p. 50:

First of all, you have to assume, say, properness of the $G$-action and local compactness of $F$ in all the definitions. Otherwise, the following will be a counter-example to all four: Start with your favorite connected Lie group  $G$ of dimension $>0$ (say, $U(1)$) and your favorite topological space $X$ (say, a point). Then $P=G\times X$ is a principal $G$-bundle. Now, consider the same group $G$ but equipped with discrete topology $G^\delta$, but keep the original topology on $P$. Take the obvious action $G^\delta\times P\to P$. This action  satisfies (1)---(4) but does not define a $G^\delta$-principal bundle.

This can be (partly) remedied by assuming that $G$ is (2nd countable!) Lie group and $F$ is a manifold. Then (2) and (3) become equivalent to the standard definition.

Here is the situation assuming the extra assumption of properness.

(1) is not equivalent to (2) even if $G$ is a compact metrizable group, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560371/orbit-space-of-a-free-proper-g-action-principal-bundle/1754706#1754706). Nevertheless, (1) $\iff$ (2) if (in (1)) $G$ is assumed to be a Lie group ($F$ need not be a manifold; this theorem is due to R.Palais).

(2) is equivalent to (3).

(3) is equivalent to (4) provided that in (4) the $G$-action on each fiber is transitive.

Answer (score 11):

For the equivalence of these definitions, I would look here: [Local triviality of principal bundles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23739/local-triviality-of-principal-bundles).

The existence of a $G$-equivariant cover is equivalent to the existence of $G$-valued transition functions:

Suppose $(U_\alpha,\Phi_\alpha)$, $\Phi_\alpha : P\vert_{U_\alpha} \to U_\alpha\times F$, is a trivializing cover.  This defines a collection of maps $\phi_\alpha : P\to F$ by
$$
\Phi_\alpha(p) = (\pi(p), \phi_\alpha(p)).
$$
For a right principal $G$-bundle, this covering is $G$-equivariant if $\phi_\alpha(pg) = \phi_\alpha(p)g$.  Now we have 
$$
\Phi_\alpha \circ \Phi_\beta^{-1} : U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \times F \to U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \times F
$$
is an isomorphism of trivial $G$-bundles and so takes the form
$$
(x, f) \mapsto (x, h_{\alpha\beta}(x,f)).
$$
If the covering is $G$-equivariant then so is this map, which means that $h_{\alpha\beta}(x,fg) = h_{\alpha\beta}(x,f)g$.  Since $G$ is acting freely and transitively, fixing a point of $F$ identities $F$ with $G$ and $h_{\alpha\beta}$ is entirely determined by the function $g_{\alpha\beta}: U_\alpha\cap U_\beta \to G, x \mapsto h_{\alpha\beta}(x,e)$.  Thus the transition functions are given by left-multiplication by $g_{\alpha\beta}$.  This is what is meant by the transition functions being $G$-valued.

Conversely, if the transition functions are $G$-valued then the trivializations will be $G$-equivariant.  This is because
$$
P = \sqcup_\alpha U_\alpha \times F/\sim, ~~ (x, f) \sim (x, g_{\alpha\beta}(x)f) \text{ for } x \in U_\alpha\cap U_\beta.
$$
The equivariance then comes from the fact that the transition functions are operating by left-multiplication, while the $G$-action is right multiplication.

Comment: Hi, Eric. Thanks so much for your answer; it's very helpful. Could you perhaps clarify one more thing for me? Definition 1 is actually [Wikipedia's definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_bundle#Formal_definition). However, I don't understand why condition (2A) ($G$ preserves fibers) is included... Isn't it redundant?

Comment: @JesseMadnick I actually meant to make the comment that (2A) is redundant.

Comment: I have one last question, which has been bugging me most of all: Does Definition (1) imply the existence of a trivializing cover with $G$-valued transition maps?

Comment: Definition (1) does imply the existence of a trivializing cover if the Lie group $G$ is compact, because then the projection map $\pi$ is a proper submersion from $P$ onto the base space $X$ and you can use Ehresmann's fibration theorem to assert the existence of a local trivialization.  Without compactness of the Lie group, I don't think the definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Eric O. Korman and @JesseMadnick, can you please help me with [this definition of principle bundle (bounty offered)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3395875/this-definition-of-principal-g-bundle-might-be-missing-details-like-fiber-pres)? It might be missing some things like Eric O. Korman's statement on equivalence, though Jason DeVito's ideas in comments seem similar to the ones in Eric O. Korman's answer

Comment: how exactly does equivariance of trivializations follow from G-valued transition maps? i'm afraid your sketch was not enough for me.
about why definition 1 implies the trivializing cover: it's already included in the definition of fiber bundle.