# Let $G$ be a compact Lie group acting on $M$. If $M/G$ is compact, does it follow that $M$ is compact?

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, group-actions

Let $G$ be a Lie group which acts smoothly, freely and properly in a smooth manifold $M$. If the group $G$ is compact and the quotient smooth manifold $M/G$ is compact, is $M$ compact?

• I proved that using only the hypothesis which the Lie group in the conditions Of the problem assures that $M$ is compact.

• I found three examples where the conjecture is valid, but I did not find counterexamples.

Comment: Using slices for the action, it is easy to show that $M$ is sequentially compact.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you intended to mean in your first bullet point. Could you please rephrase and/or elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Under these hypotheses, the quotient map $M\to M/G$ is a principal $G$-bundle, i.e. it is locally trivial (see [Local triviality of principal bundles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23739/local-triviality-of-principal-bundles), for instance).  Since $M/G$ is compact, it can be covered by finitely many open subsets $U_1,\dots,U_n$ for which $M\to M/G$ is trivial over the closures $\overline{U_1},\dots,\overline{U_n}$.  Then $M$ is covered by sets which are homeomorphic to $\overline{U_1}\times G,\dots \overline{U_n}\times G$.  Each of these sets is compact, and so $M$ is compact.